# jquery width not working

Tags: jquery, css

am trying to add css for an element that is being added after being received via JSON. the code is as follows:

```
success: function(data)    
{
   var div =   $("<div>").addClass("col-xs-12");
   var a =     $("<a>").prop('href', data.ad_link).prop('target','_system');
   var img =   $("<img>").addClass('img-responsive center-block ad_image img-thumbnail').prop('src', data.image_url).width('50%;');
   $(a).append($(img));
   $(div).append($(a));
   $(div).appendTo($("#Advertisement"));
}
```

have tried adding width with `css('width','50%;')` and with `prop('style','width: 50%;')` but it does not seem to apply.

any help appreciated.

Comment: remove `;` from 50% width. Use `css('width','50%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that `;` semi-colon

```
.width('50%');
```

Please read here to know more about [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Comment: thank you .. seems to be working. unexpected issue though :)

Comment: @AbdulAli Nothing unexpected, `;` is invalid there... and an upvote for the answer cuz I just realized that you answered much before the comment :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks for your edit and your encouragement.! :)